# Is there any Apache Click maven archtype similar to Wicket's?

Tags: maven, click-framework

Is there any Apache Click maven archetype similar to Wicket's quick start?  Similar to http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html 
Basically what I need is a way to get started using Apache Click quickly using Maven.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never tried it myself, but [this project](http://code.google.com/p/construtor/) provides a [maven archetype for click](http://code.google.com/p/construtor/source/browse/#svn/trunk/maven-archetype-click). It doesn't look like they provide it in a public repository, so you will need to check the sources, compile&install it and than you'll be able to use it, e.g.:

```
$ svn checkout http://construtor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ construtor-read-only
$ cd construtor-read-only/maven-archetype-click/
$ mvn clean install
$ mvn archetype:generate
[...]
387: local -> maven-archetype-click (An archetype which generates a simplifed sample of the Apache Click Framework.)
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of future enquirers, there are instructions to achieve this [here](https://code.google.com/p/construtor/wiki/MavenArchetypeClickSetup). **However**, the remote build did not work for me using Maven 3 nor did the local installation suggested without some modifications. This is what worked for me:

1. Download the [archetype jar file](https://construtor.googlecode.com/files/maven-archetype-click-1.0.jar)
2. Install the archetype in the local maven 3 repo:

   mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.google.constructor.archetypes -DartifactId=maven-archetype-click -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=\maven-archetype-click-1.0.jar
3. Generate skeleton project:

   mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.google.constructor.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-click -DarchetypeVersion=1.0 -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=clickprimer -DarchetypeCatalog=local
4. cd clickprimer
5. mvn clean package
6. mvn jetty:run